# Can I change product version with my customize string in wix?

Tags: wix, velo

Version in our project in the format: **TOOP_V9.1_PR0000 or 00.99.00_SNRF_GPU** and so on, and created as branch name.Product version of any binary should look like **'x.x.x.x'** where x is an integer from 0 to 65534. But here I want to modify the version with string. Is it possible to **change** product format version to **string** in **wix file** for installers?

Comment: If you use major upgrades only I suppose you can change the ProductName instead of the ProductVersion?

Comment: Thanks for the information, Even if we modify the product name,how installer version will reflect with my customized string saying I want to modify version as "00.00.00_snrf_gpu."

Comment: As mentioned by you "Major upgrades only " How it will be related to product version ? Can you please brief it?

Answer (score 0):

All properties in Windows Installer are strings.

Windows Installer Product Version is Major.Minor.Build 0-255 . 0-255 . 0-65535

What you do *after* those first three required fields are up to you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/productversion

Comment: Thanks for the information. Actually I have tried to put "00.00.00.snrf_gpu" but compiler shows error saying "00.00.20.snrf_gpu", is not a valid version.  Legal version values should look like 'x.x.x.x' where x is an integer from 0 to 65534". I am writing the code in wix, Please help, how to proceed further?

Comment: Ah, I forgot this was a "WiX" question and not just an MSI question.  WiX is more restrictive then MSI.   You may need to write a postbuild step to update the MSI without WiX knowing about it.